# Is it correct to use 'to wait for' in the following context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am very confused about the use of "***to be***" and didn't find any proper explanation anywhere till now. Could someone please help me understand it? For example, what is the difference between the following sentences?

> It is not acceptable **to be waiting** for...
>
> it is not acceptable **to wait** for...

Comment: What does your dictionary tell you about the meaning of the verb **to be?** Do you know the difference between the _simple present_ and _present continuous_ tenses in English? Please tell us what research you have done.

Comment: Here is explanation from my dictionary to–be

\tə-ˈbē\

adjective

: that is to be : future — usually usedpostpositively and often incombination <a bride-to-be>

Comment: That is **not** a definition of the _verb_ **to be.** It is a definition of the _adjectival_ "to be" as in "bride to be." Do you understand the difference between an adjective and a verb? More important, do you know the difference between the _simple present_ and _present continuous_ tenses in English?

Comment: @P.E.Dant - Oh, please – stop with the "What does your dictionary say" comment. It's one thing to exhort a user to share more specifics about their research besides "I didn't find anything," but I would never send a learner to a [dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/be_1) to learn more about _to be_, perhaps one of the trickiest verbs in all of English. The opposite side of the show-your-research coin is [remember our mission](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1160/have-we-forgotten-our-mission).

Comment: While searching "to be" on internet, I found sentences with is, am, are, was, were + infinitive + ing. I also saw sentences with will be + infinitive + ing. I have no confusion about these sentences. I am confused with the use of "to be + infinitive + ing". I haven't seen any explanation that describe this type of sentences.

Comment: @J.R. Fine, you wouldn't send a learner to look up _to be,_ and I would, that's clear. "Mission" is a little grandiose for a low-traffic site, but I do have a _plan,_ and I don't think _to be_ is too diificult for this or any other questioner. Why do you underestimate them? The dictionary provides at least a baseline, and unless I know what a questioner has read, I can't assist at all. The verb _to be_ is not taught well, the way I see it. It's central to lots of things in English, but it's taught as if it is a meaningless grunt.

Comment: I have confusion and that's the reason I am  asking for help.

Comment: If you can't, simply say you can't help.

Comment: @Sa1 In your second sentence, the verb _be_ is used to form the _progressive infinitive_ of the verb _wait._

Comment: @P.E.Dant - I've just seen a lot of "What does the dictionary tell you?" comments of late. Some of them are justified, but some of them seem a bit quick-triggered, unwelcoming, and not very sympathetic to the learner. By the way, I don't underestimate the learners here – I'm merely calling for a balance between brusqueness and civility.

Comment: @J.R. I heartily agree that the exhortation can be and is sometimes abused. Me, I use it to establish a baseline. Especially when a question includes no research, I need to know what they know.

Comment: @P.E. - I admire your motives; you might want to work on your wording. :-) Had you asked, "What research have you done about the verb **to be**," I probably would have upvoted your comment. I was only taking exception to the "what does your dictionary say" part. There is more to research than a dictionary, and sometimes dictionaries aren't the best places to look for information. I get particularly annoyed when an OP is asking about something like nuances of prepositions, and the first thing posted is "What does your dictionary say?" – as if a dictionary would make it obvious what _on_ means.

Comment: In my opinion, both statements sound equivalent in meanings, although they may be different from a grammatical viewpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your phrases use an infinitive form of the verb *wait.* The first uses the ordinary infinitive:

> It is not acceptable *to wait* for...

In your second phrase, the verb *be* is used to form the *progressive infinitive* of the verb *wait.*

> It is not acceptable *to be waiting* for...

We use progressive forms and tenses to talk about conditions or actions that are (or were, or will be)  *in progress* at the time we are talking about.

It is sometimes idiomatic to use the *progressive infinitive* to emphasize the action that is described by the verb. Compare:

> It's about time for us *to be going.*
>   It's about time for us *to go.*
>
> Isn't it a little late *to be driving?*
>   Isn't it a little late *to drive?*
>
> It is not right *to be bothering* him like that.
>   It is not right *to bother* him like that.

There is little difference in meaning between the two phrases in your example, and very often the *progressive infinitive,* especially in the present tense, does not add anything to the sense of the verb.

StoneyB's answer to a related question [**here**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/68080/37009) may also be helpful.